# Issues with select date from the datepicker with Appium for Android Driver

Tags: android, datepicker, appium

I am facing issues selecting a date from the datepicker with Appium for Android Driver. Please check the screenshot of the Calender I am looking for.

[image]

I have already tried with `element.clear()` followed by `element.sendkey("text")`, but it's not working.

Also I tried to work with `Scroll` to followed by `TouchAction`, where it's working until the Year is selected, but after that it fails to select the date and month which should be selected from the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can anyone please suggest on this ,how to tackle the issue.So far tried with all the possible options like DatePicker,Number Picker with Xpath,Class,SendKeys,Scroll To and unfortunately nothing works so far.

Comment: could you share the corresponding appium inspector/uiautomator viewer details as well. though seems like date picker is not governed by the app developers which could possibly result in missing attributes to access them

Comment: any updates over the same, i believe the same has been raised on github as well?